circular random walk - markovian frog
Suppose there are $n$ lily pads on a unite circle. A frog is sitting on one of them at time $t=0$. Every minute, this frog makes a jump to a neighboring lily pad with a probability $p=1/2$. Find the expected time - one jump per minute - for this frog to visit every lily pad on the unit circle.
Here is my approach: suppose we have $n=4$ lily pad. Suppose the frog is sitting on lily pad $i=1$ and lily pad $i=n$ is the absorbing state. In that case, I write the $3\times 3$ matrix with the following non-zero components: $M_{12}=M_{21}=M_{23}=M_{32}=1/2$. Then, one can find the fundamental matrix, $\mathbf{N}=(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{Q})^{-1}$ ($\mathbf{I}$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix). Then, the sum of the first row of $\mathbf{N}$ gives the expected time of $3$.
I am not sure about my approach. I would appreciate any tips about this problem

Do you mean the frog jumps to the next pad with probability $\frac12$ or else doesn't move, or that it jumps clockwise or anticlockwise with equal probability?

It does not stay on the pad. It either moves forward or backward, each with a probability of 1/2.

In that case don't forget the frog can switch direction. So it could visit the four pads in the order $1$, $2$, $1$, $4$, $3$. Pad $n$ needn't be the last pad.

That is a great point. How should i then think about formulating my approach?

You could make the state be a triplet of pads $(x, a, b)$ where $x$ is the current pad of the frog and $(a,b)$ are the bounds where the frog has visited. You start from $(1,1,1)$ and you can jump to $(2, 2, 1)$ or to $(n, 1, n)$ and so on. Make all the states where $a=b (\neq 1)$ absorping.

I think you can actually solve it as series of sub-problems: since when the boundary is increased, the frog is always at an end of the boundary and those ends are symmetric, you will get the answer by summing the expected times to increase the boundary by $1$ and those are just linear random walks where you start next to one end and both ends are absorping.

For what it's worth, numerical simulation suggests the expected time to occupy $n$ pads is $T_{n-1}=\binom{n}{2}=\frac12 n(n-1)$.

The set of states the frog has visited is always a contiguous block. It can grow on both ends as the frog can traverse back and forth in the visited block. That block needs to grow $n-1$ times. The situation after a growth of the block is symmetric: the frog is in one end of the block and for the block to grow, the frog must reach one further on either side of the block.

Therefore, the expected number of steps before visiting all pads is the sum of the expected number of steps to grow the block from $m$ to $m+1$, for $m=1,2,\dots, n-1$. So let us fix $m$ and solve this problem. It's a symmetric random walk on $0,1,2,\dots, m+1$ with both ends absorping (see picture). Call the expected number of steps before absorption when starting from the state $k$ as $E(k)$. We want $E(1)$ (which by symmetry is equal to $E(m)$) We have the recursion
$$
\begin{align}
E(0) &= 0 \\
E(1) &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}E(0) + \frac{1}{2}E(2) \\
E(2) &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}E(1) + \frac{1}{2}E(3) \\
\vdots \\
E(m+1) &= 0 
\end{align}
$$
In other words
$$
E(k) - 2E(k-1) + E(k-2) = -2 \tag{1} \\
E(0) = E(m+1) = 0
$$
Let's subtract (1) for $k-1$ from (1) for $k$ to get the homogenous $E(k)-3E(k-1)+3E(k-2)-E(k-3)=0$. This has the general solution $E(k)=ak^2+bk+c$, since $1$ is the only root of the characteristic equation. Because $E$ needs to satisfy (1), we have
$$
ak^2+bk+c = 2(a(k-1)^2+b(k-1)+c) - (a(k-2)^2+b(k-2)+c) - 2
$$
This must be satisfied identically. So we must have $a=-1$. Solving $b$ and $c$ from the boundary conditions, we get $E(k) = k(m-k+1)$. So $E(1) = m$.
Remember we must sum the values of $E_m(1) = m$ for $m=1,2,\dots n-1$ to get the expected time to grow the visiting block to its full size (note: I didn't write the subscript $m$ above to make notation cleaner). So the answer to the original problem is
$$
1+2+\dots + n-1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$

Thanks @ploosu2, (a) can you explain how you obtained $E(k)=2E(k-1)-E(k-2)-2$ and (b) how one can go from $E(k)=k(m-k+1)$ to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$?

@user147813 (a) It's the conditioning on first step thing, I added the original unmanipulated group of equations, hope it's clearer from that. (b) Remember that $E(1) = E_m(1)$ (it depends on $m$) is the solution to the sub-problem of growing the visited block from $m$ to $m+1$.

@user To be honest, I just asked WA: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+recurrence+E%28k%29%3D2E%28k-1%29-E%28k-2%29-2  But isn't the general solution given by a special solution to the inhomogenous (which we can guess) plus the general solution to the homogenous? So the solution space is two dimensional. If you use homogenizing, I guess the third constant is solved from the fact that the difference of the equations for $k+1$ and $k$ needs to be identically the constant $-2$.

@user Sorry, I misspoke the third constant is solved from the inhomogenous equation itself: it needs to satisfied identically.

@user I edited this in the answer.

I thought i understood it before but was wrong. can you explain in detail how you get $E(k)=2E(k-1)-E(k-2)-2$. I'm clear on everything else. Thanks.

@user147813 From the state $k-1$ you can jump to $k-2$ or to $k$ (except the ends, where you already have $E=0$). So $E(k-1) = \frac{1}{2}(1+E(k-1)) + \frac{1}{2}(1+E(k))$. This is the conditioning on whether you jump to left or right. In both cases the expectation is $1$ for the one jump you made in addition to the expectation from the  landed state.  The equation (1) is gotten by multiplying by two and moving terms around. Maybe it was a bit misleading to put $E(k)$ on the other side, since this equation "is gotten from" $k-1$. I'll edit (1) to be $E(k)-2E(k-1)+E(k-2) = -2$.

you probably mean $\frac{1}{2}(1+E(k-2))$? Otherwise makes sense. Thanks!
